# Angularjs Standard File Names

Tags: angularjs, naming

The [recommendations document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XXMvReO8-Awi1EZXAXS4PzDzdNvV6pGcuaF4Q9821Es/pub) tells me the following:

> Each filename should describe the file's purpose by including the
>   component or view sub-section that it's in, and the type of object
>   that it is as part of the name. For example, a datepicker directive
>   would be in components/datepicker/datepicker-directive.js.

e.g.

```
app/
----- shared/
---------- sidebar/
--------------- sidebarDirective.js
--------------- sidebarView.html
---------- article/
--------------- articleDirective.js
--------------- articleView.html
```

While the paragraph explains that these should be the filenames, it does not explain *why* these should be the filenames.

This violates the DRY principle. I would imagine the files should be named as such:

```
app/
----- shared/
---------- sidebar/
--------------- directive.js
--------------- view.html
---------- article/
--------------- directive.js
--------------- view.html
```

It seems to me the recommended filenames are longer than they need to be. Does anyone know why the filename would include the component name when the containing folder already reveals that?

Comment: I personally just name those as index.js and index.whatever if those are main item under that folder. xD

Answer (score 1):

I think names should be more descriptive. it doesn't matter in which folder you are, so here I am adding one snap of my folder structure hope it help you well.[image: folder structure and file name recommendation]